# Calling external *.exe with Python with arguments, no errors but getting no output

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I have *.exe program which takes simple command to create a user (in cmd):
I open cmd, navigate to my.exe location, then run it like that:

my.exe cu username password email

cu - is a command that is used by my.exe to create users.

As I have many users to create, I want to run my.exe with python.

I am getting no errors but users are not created. I have done it manually in cmd and no problems. As I am not familiar with this module of python, I don't quite understand what's going on.

My script:

```
# import details for users from csv and write them to a list:
import csv
with open(r'C:\temp\test.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    users_list = list(reader) # list of lists

# run my.exe for each list entry, each is a list as well
import subprocess
for each in users_list:
    arguments = 'cu' +" "+ str(each[0])  +" "+ str(each[1]) +" "+ str(each[2])
    subprocess.call([r"C:\Software\ikfbatool\ikfbatool.exe", arguments])
```

Comment: You're using `subprocess.call()` incorrectly.  You have to pass arguments as separate list items, not as one big string.  i.e. something like `subprocess.call(['command.exe', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'])`

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass the arguments as a long string and it is not correct. In your case your list will contain 2 elements, only the `.exe` and a string which contains the arguments.

> All members of command should be separated in list.

**You should try:**

```
arguments = ['cu', str(each[0]), str(each[1]), str(each[2])]
subprocess.call([r"C:\Software\ikfbatool\ikfbatool.exe"].extend(arguments))
```